# Customizing Google Site Search submit button?

Tags: javascript, css, google-custom-search

I have managed to customize the styling of the google site search search field and button, however I can't figure out how to get rid of the "Search" text that displays on the search button.

Basically, I have replaced the css/text-based button with an image, however as you can see with the image below it still has the "Search" text on top of it.

Is there anyway to get rid of this or do I have to resort to doing something like `text-indent: -9999px;` ?

My CSS for the button is:

```
.cse input.gsc-search-button,
input.gsc-search-button {
  width: 103px;
  min-width: 103px;
  height: 36px;
  min-height: 36px;
  border: none;
  background: url('../images/search-btn.png') left top no-repeat;
}
```

Image of the button:

[image]

Site Search Code:

```
<div id='cse' style='width: 100%;'>Loading</div>
<script src='//www.google.com/jsapi' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
google.load('search', '1', {language: 'en', style: src="<?=ROOT_URL?>css/default.css"});
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
  var customSearchOptions = {};
  var customSearchControl =   new google.search.CustomSearchControl('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', customSearchOptions);
  customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
  var options = new google.search.DrawOptions();
  customSearchControl.draw('cse', options);
}, true);
</script>
```

Comment: Can't you manipulate the element in JavaScript and set the innerHTML value to *""* ?

Comment: `color:transparent;`?

Comment: @Ghillied Possibly, but just wondering if there was a "proper" way to do it with the google options or what not.

Comment: @Juhana That did it haha. Feel free to post as an answer and I will accept it :)

Comment: @Juhana Actaully, that doesn't work in IE8 haha...... only FF & Chrome.